# pandas sort_values throws ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a following `DataFrame` schema:

| str_A | str_B | co_A | co_B | ... | co_X |

where `co_A` and `co_B` stand for **custom objects**

Those objects inherit `object` and have defined rich comparison methods

FWIW: `__hash__` method is also overriden and calls `super().__hash__()`

What I want to do is to sort by the two custom columns and here is where the confusion comes.

The following code works as expected:

```
df.sort_values(by=['str_A', 'str_B'])
```

The following code works as well:

```
df.sort_values(by=['co_A'])
```

but what doesn't work is:

```
df.sort_values(by=['co_A', 'co_B'])
```

which throws

> ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique

And it turns out that some combinations of `co_x` and `str_x` do work, others do not.

I thought it might be cause of mixed types and so I dropped the string values and left only the custom objects, the error persists. I am clueless here and I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: I am using pandas version 0.23.0

To generate a simple data which I can reproduce the issue with, the following sample code can be used

```
def feed():
    return type('Feed', (), {
        attr: names.get_first_name() if attr.startswith('substr') else names.get_last_name()
        for attr in CPE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_LIST
    })

feed = [feed() for i in range(100)]
```

**EDIT2**:

I am using jupyter notebook, the `CustomObject` class is imported from a lib.

What I did is I created another simple class directly in the jupyter with the similar methods as the original one to check whether there is something wrong with the data... **and it worked. Which is even more confusing. There must be something wrong with the CustomObject class** (I did not write the class, however, I can not find anything that could cause the issue).

The class is supposed to handle version comparisons -- the specification can be found in the gist
https://gist.github.com/CermakM/011f17e91ffe9efbe35f29738fb23ec2

**EDIT3**: Found the root cause of the issue, don't know how to solve it, yet

Having implemented CustomObject like

```
class CustomObject:

    def __init__(self, stream: str):
        if stream is None:
            raise TypeError()

        self.stream = stream

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{cls!s}(stream={stream!r})".format(
            cls=self.__class__.__name__,
            stream=self.stream
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return "{stream!s}".format(
            stream=self.stream
        )

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False

        return self.stream < other.stream

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return True

        return self.stream > other.stream

    # <<<<<<< This causes the issue 
    #     def __eq__(self, other):
    #         if other is None:
    #             return False

    #         return self.stream == other.stream
    # =======

    def __hash__(self):
        return super().__hash__()
```

It works as expected without the commented code above.

Comment: Are you using pandas 0.23.0?

Comment: Can you provide some data which demonstrates this issue?

Comment: Added those informations to my question, thanks for the notes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same problem.

#### Cause

The problem is that your `__hash__` function should always return `True` when two objects are the equal (as defined by your `__eq__` function).

Right now this is not the case because your equivalence is based on the `stream` attribute and your class uses the `__hash__` function of `object` which is (I believe) based on the objects location in memory.

#### Solution

Defining your hash function as below might do the trick.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.stream)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Thought it was dead already .. Yes, I found that out the hard way. I supposed that I could have equivalence defined separately from the hash function. That is hashes might not equal, but objects will compare equivalent by the `==` sign. This was obviously wrong assumption. __Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.__ 
Problem here was that hash must not change during object lifetime and the `stream` attribute does, so I couldn't use your solution.